# Listing other project class method's

Tags: java, class, methods, eclipse-plugin, workbench

I have problem accessing class methods. My task is to make eclipse plug-in to get selected file's (from another project), name of class and list out class methods. I figured out how to get class name, but i don't know how to access that class as an class (Class <?>). Here's what I've got

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    String className = "";
    Object firstElement;

    ISelectionService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();
    IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service.getSelection();

    /* Getting first element of selected structure (path and workspace)*/
    firstElement = structured.getFirstElement();
    IResource resource = (IResource) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(firstElement, IResource.class);

    /* Extracting class name from selected object */
    className = resource.getName();
}
```

Now that I've got class name extracted I'm trying to get that class methods. This is a method that I'm using for getting class methods

```
public static Collection<Method> getMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
    Collection<Method> found = new ArrayList<Method>();
    while (clazz != null) {
        for (Method m1 : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            boolean overridden = false;
            for (Method m2 : found) {
                if (m2.getName().equals(m1.getName())
                        && Arrays.deepEquals(m1.getParameterTypes(), m2.getParameterTypes())) {
                    overridden = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!overridden)
                found.add(m1);
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return found;
}
```

Main problem: Don't know how to access this class as an class. It's accessing it as an compilation unit. Because of this when **Collection getMethods(Class clazz)** is called i don't get any method list. This is how I tryed calling it

```
    Class<?> clazz1 = firstElement.getClass();
    Collection<Method> found1 = new ArrayList<Method>();
    found1 = getMethods(clazz1);
```

Return value is []. Any ideas what to do?

Sorry for bad language and long explanation, I'm rookie with java, just started.

EDIT:
Forgot to add, this is what I get in "firstElement" variable after calling structured.getFirstElement()

```
[Working copy] Test.java [in org.eclipse.testing [in src [in TestingProject]]]
package org.eclipse.testing
class Test
int myInt
Test()
int someInt()
static String someString()
```

So as I see it, firstElement has structure, containing class and methods, but I don't know how to parse them, and extract list of methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Methodvisitor and "visit" all methods in a CompilationUnit, something like this:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.*;

    ICompilationUnit unit = ...;
    MethodVisitor visitor = createMethodVisitor(unit);

    public class MethodVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

        List<MethodDeclaration> methods = new ArrayList<MethodDeclaration>();

        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {

            node.getName();
            return super.visit(node);
        }

        public List<MethodDeclaration> getMethods() {
            return methods;
        }
    } `
```

Comment: Could you explain it more specific?